# How to use my own router as DHCP server when ISP modem router does not support bridge?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, dhcp

I'm currently using a GPON router (ZTE F660) from my ISP. I'm planning to purchase `TP-LINK N600 TL-WDR3600` as secondary router and use that instead for my LAN and WLAN because the GPON router (main router) from ISP gave me alot of trouble like wired LAN cannot see each other, poor signal range, etc.

I search the internet and the solution is to change the main router to bridge mode. But the problem is I don't see such setting in my main router (it's probably locked and let's just assume it is).

So my question is :
1. Can I just link ethernet cable to one of the slot in my main router and 2ndary router without using the DHCP from main router?
2. Is there any downside for example like slower bandwidth and higher latency for doing this?
3. I also need to SSH my Raspberry Pi from the internet, is it going to be a problem when the device is sitting behind 2 routers?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Aside from the answer that you do not necessarily need to set your modem as bridged, you can often call your ISP and request them to do it. They can login to your modem and set it to bridged.

Comment: @LPChip is correct, however if you have Comcast you're better off getting it bridged via an admin on their support forums, 98% of the normal call takers have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah I give my ISP a call before making this post, the CS have no idea what I'm talking and just told me to restart the router if it's not working. Anyway I'm wondering if the main router is set to bridge, will I still able to use the internet if I plug my computer directly to main router?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions.

Plugging the WAN interface of your router into the LAN interface of the ZTE F660 will work, however it will do double-nat, which will make some protocol baulk (mainly P2P stuff).

I don't have an F660, so I can't be absolutely sure, but in most cases you can fix this problem by

(1) Configuring your N600 to use a different IP range to the F660 (eg 10.x.x.x instead of 192.168.x.x) and 
(2)Instructing the N600 to route requests to 10.x.x.x via your N600.    You will need to assign the WAN address on your N600 statically then
(3)  Turn off NAT on your N600.